# Could not find method python() for arguments error in IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I am trying to add python modules, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find method python() for arguments
```

after adding build.gradle file the following

```
dependencies {
 python spec.external.numpy
 python spec.external.pandas
}
```

Has anybody encountered a similar problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add python plugin?

Comment: @y.bedrov yes i did, which is what makes it weird..

Comment: Is it possible to share project sample?

Comment: i cannot share the whole thing, but in product-spec.json, I added

        "gradle-python": {
            "libraries": [
              "gradle-python"
            ],
            "version": "2.*"
          }

Comment: Isn't  it reproducible with new sample project?